# How do I seperate data in R by category

Tags: r

Say I have the data frame (image below) and I want to split in to two new categories based on region so one would be BC and the other NZ, how do I achieve this? (in R)
[data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/64ZvX.jpg)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overlow! Currently, your data is poorly formatted. One of the many good ways to share data is using the `dput()` function in R. E.g. if your data frame is named `df`, you can use `dput(df)`

Comment: what is your expected output ?

Comment: Do you want to split it into two data.frames?

Comment: well I'm not sure if I need new data frames the intention is to be able to graph the variables for both categories later on. Would I need new data frames?

Comment: No, you don't want to split it for plotting.

Comment: What would you recommend doing instead?

Comment: can you briefly elaborate on the plot you want to create? should both categories be on it or do you want to create a separate plot for each category?

Comment: Delete this post (has no relevance anymore) and try learning either base plots or ggplot2 (which is far more popular). Just give it time - it is worth it.

Comment: @alex_jwb90 seperate plot for each BC & NZ and a basic scatter plot, I know how to plot for basic stuff, but I have never had two categories in one category (if  that makes sense) , categories for one variable.

Comment: If splitting it is not the correct thing to do then what should I to get the data and for each BC and NZ as seperate?

Comment: I also I need to a simple regression on both regions.

Comment: To have two separate plots in the context of Len's answer below, try using `ggplot(mtcars,aes(disp,mpg)) + geom_point(aes(color = am)) + facet_wrap(~am)`. `facet_wrap` will create a separate plot for each group of the variable you provide.

Comment: @alex_jwb90 - looks like we had the same idea, as I was adding the `facet_wrap()` version of my answer while you posted your comment.

Comment: Then, when I use a linear model for each region what do I put because I still have two regions?

Comment: See updates to my answer for illustration of how to run a regression analysis by group, using a split variable. Alternately, one can use a single model to represent the same thing by including the factor variable in the regression, as well as an interaction effect between the categorical and continuous variables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an example with the `mtcars` data where we use  the transmission variable `am` to plot different groups in a scatterplot with the `ggplot2` package.

We will create a scatterplot with the displacement variable on the `x` axis and miles per gallon on the `y` axis. Since cars with larger engine displacement typically consume more gasoline than those with smaller displacement, we expect to see a negative relationship (mpg is higher with low values of displacement) in the chart.

First, we convert `am` to a factor variable so the legend prints two categories instead of a continuum between 0 and 1. Then we use `ggplot()` and `geom_point()` to set the point color based on the value of `am`.

```
library(ggplot2)
mtcars$am <- factor(mtcars$am,labels = c("automatic","manual"))
ggplot(mtcars,aes(disp,mpg,group = am)) +
     geom_point(aes(color = am))
```

...and the output:

[image]

### Separating charts by group with facets

We can use `ggplot2` directly to generate separate charts by a grouping variable. In `ggplot2` this is known as a facetted chart. We use `facet_wrap()` to split the data by values of `am` as follows.

```
ggplot(mtcars,aes(disp,mpg,group = am)) +
     geom_point() +
     facet_wrap(mtcars$am,ncol = 2)
```

...and the output:

[image]

### Adding regression line and confidence intervals

Given the comments in the original question, we an add a regression line to the plot by using the `geom_smooth()` function, which defaults to lowess smoothing.

```
ggplot(mtcars,aes(disp,mpg,group = am)) +
     geom_point() +
     facet_wrap(mtcars$am,ncol = 2) + 
     geom_smooth(span = 1)
```

...and the output:

[image]

To use a simple regression instead of lowess smoothing, we use the `method =` argument in `geom_smooth()`, and set it to `lm`.

```
ggplot(mtcars,aes(disp,mpg,group = am)) +
     geom_point() +
     facet_wrap(mtcars$am,ncol = 2) + 
     geom_smooth(method = "lm")
```

...and the output:

[image]

## Generate regression models by group

Here we split the data frame by values of `am`, and use `lapply()` to generate regression models for each group.

```
carsList <- split(mtcars,mtcars$am)
lapply(carsList,function(x){
     summary(lm(mpg ~ disp,data = x))

})
```

...and the output:

```
$automatic

Call:
lm(formula = mpg ~ disp, data = x)

Residuals:
    Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max 
-2.7341 -1.6546 -0.8855  1.6032  5.0764 

Coefficients:
             Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept) 25.157064   1.592922   15.79 1.36e-11 ***
disp        -0.027584   0.005146   -5.36 5.19e-05 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Residual standard error: 2.405 on 17 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-squared:  0.6283,    Adjusted R-squared:  0.6064 
F-statistic: 28.73 on 1 and 17 DF,  p-value: 5.194e-05


$manual

Call:
lm(formula = mpg ~ disp, data = x)

Residuals:
    Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max 
-4.6056 -2.4200 -0.0956  3.1484  5.2315 

Coefficients:
            Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept) 32.86614    1.95033  16.852 3.33e-09 ***
disp        -0.05904    0.01174  -5.031 0.000383 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Residual standard error: 3.545 on 11 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-squared:  0.6971,    Adjusted R-squared:  0.6695 
F-statistic: 25.31 on 1 and 11 DF,  p-value: 0.0003834
```

**NOTE:** since this is an example illustrating the code necessary to generate a regression analysis with a split variable, we won't go into the details about whether the data here conforms to modeling assumptions for Ordinary Least Squares regression.

### Modeling the groups in one regression model

As I noted in the comments, we can account for the differences between automatic and manual transmissions in one regression model if we specify the `am` effect as well as an interaction effect between `am` and `disp`.

```
summary(lm(mpg ~ disp + am + am * disp,data=mtcars))
```

We can demonstrate that this model generates the same predictions as the split model for manual transmissions by generating predictions from each model as follows.

```
data <- data.frame(am = c(1,1,0),
                   disp = c(157,248,300))
data$am <- factor(data$am,labels = c("automatic","manual"))
mod1 <- lm(mpg ~ disp + am + am * disp,data=mtcars)
predict(mod1,data)
mod2 <- lm(mpg ~ disp,data = mtcars[mtcars$am == "manual",])
predict(mod2,data[data$am == "manual",])
```

...and the output:

```
> data <- data.frame(am = c(1,1,0),
+                    disp = c(157,248,300))
> data$am <- factor(data$am,labels = c("automatic","manual"))
> mod1 <- lm(mpg ~ disp + am + am * disp,data=mtcars)
> predict(mod1,data)
       1        2        3 
23.59711 18.22461 16.88199 
> mod2 <- lm(mpg ~ disp,data = mtcars[mtcars$am == "manual",])
> predict(mod2,data[data$am == "manual",])
       1        2 
23.59711 18.22461
```

We subset the data prior to `predict()` for the split model in order to generate predictions only for observations that had manual transmissions. Since the predictions match, we prove that building separate models by transmission type is no different than a fully specified model that includes both the categorical `am` effect and an interaction effect for `am * disp`.